# Does a python model exist that will do full auto-arima for time series data?

Tags: python, time-series, arima

Does a python model exist that will do full auto-arima for time series data?  Preferably with a slkearn style interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply googling "python auto arima" leads to https://pypi.org/project/pmdarima/ which, quote, has an

> user-friendly estimator interface for programmers familiar with scikit-learn.

Looks like it's just the thing for you. See [the documentation](https://www.alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/tips_and_tricks.html#tips-and-tricks) for details.

Answer (score 2):

[sktime](https://www.sktime.org/en/latest/) aims to be "A unified framework for machine learning with time series." It's [AutoARIMA](https://www.sktime.org/en/latest/api_reference/modules/auto_generated/sktime.forecasting.arima.AutoARIMA.html#sktime.forecasting.arima.AutoARIMA) class wraps pmdarima's class which wraps statsmodels' class.

sktime mimics the scikit-learn interface in terms of fit, predict, etc.